# Multipul emails sent to single address, when only one should have been sent. AWS SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Im using Amazon SES Mailer (Link: https://github.com/geoloqi/Amazon-SES-Mailer-PHP) and a simple loop in PHP to send an email to each email address on a list.

To make sure the emails were going out I attached my own email address to each list. (multiple lists are not send all at once)

Each list has a unique email for it.

Once in a while every few lists that go out (that have no duplicate email addresses in them), I received up to 4 copies of the same email. I can only assume my customers also are receiving these duplicated emails.

Ive checked over my code again and again and I can't see any way a request is being made more than once for each address.

The first time I noticed this I'd sent an email to a list of about 200 addresses, according to amazon SES Management Console it sent over 3000 emails.

Why!?

I've seen other posts on the AWS SES Forums about this issue, but all of them have no responses. So i thought I'd try here.

Here's the guts of my script.

http://pastebin.com/TUk7bci8

Edit: Ive checked the headers of the emails and there are different ID's for each email, I've heard that means somehow my code has sent duplicates, but I cant figure out how.

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're building the emails in a loop, but forgetting to clear the `To:` addresses on each loop, so each loop sends to everyone you've already sent to, plus whatever 'new' person you've fetched on the current iteration, so:

```
while($row = fetch_row_from_db()) {
   $to .= $row['email'];  <---concatenating, not resetting.
   send_email($to, $message);
}
```

so for the first result you fetch, $to is `a@b.c`. On the next iteration, it's `a@b.c d@e.f`, then `a@b.c d@e.f g@h.i` and so on...

Of course, this is just a guess. You've provided no code at all, so for all I know the problem is really because your server is frustrated from not getting to see the Venus/Sun transit due to clouds and is making your life miserable because of it.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why it was sending multipul emails, but I rebuilt my code with JavaScript, making axjax calls to PHP and it works fine now. :) No more duplicates yay! xD